# How to cache entire video file for later offline playback via video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, video, html5-video

Is there a way to cache the entire video file, for later offline playback via video tag?

Will the browser use data cached by AJAX GET requests of the different video file chunks?

Or I must go the ugly way and use some kind of hidden video tag + fast forward combination, letting the browser do the dirty work?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download the whole file with an XMLHttpRequest, turn it into Blob, and get a URL for it with URL.createObjectURL(). Then use that URL in the  tag. (I haven't tried this, at least not recently.)

This might not be a great idea with very large video files.